# What is the most probable cause of this leak?

Tags: jeep, leak, oil-leak, fuel-leak

I’m heading over to purchase this 1998 Jeep Laredo and one of the photos online showed this leak on the underside. Any idea what it might be?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears to be the TRANSFER CASE:

[image: Transfer Case]

and it appears to be leaking.  This could very well be an expensive problem.  I'd walk away from this "deal" if I were you.

Comment: Agree it looks like the transfer box that is leaking.  I wouldn’t necessarily walk away from it, depending how good the deal is.  It probably isn’t a major job to fix the leak.

Comment: As a purchaser my thinking would be if it's leaking there it's bound to be leaking other places @HandyHowie

Comment: I’m with Howie on this. Have you checked out the value of the vehicle on [Kelley Blue Book?](https://kbb.com)  Type in make, model, year, mileage, and condition. Is the deal well below that number?  That’s your guide here. And as for how hard to fix?  Dunno. Bad seal isn’t too bad. Excessive wear in shaft sleeves causing seal leak is an expensive repair. Good luck!